# Densely Defined Complex Operator is Symmetric if and only if $\langle T(x), x \rangle$ is Real.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

It's simple to prove that symmetric implies $\langle T(x), x \rangle$ is real for all $x \in D(T)$.

The converse is stated in John B. Conway A Course in Functional Analysis  1997, p. 309,, and in Kreyszig - Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications, p.534. Neither offer proofs: **can anyone provide a proof ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sesquilinear form $q(x,y)$ is linear in the first coordinate and conjugate linear in the second. Any sesquilinear form such as $q(x,y)=(Tx,y)$ can be recovered from its associated bilinear form $b(x)=(Tx,x)$ through the polarization identity
$$
            q(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n b(x+i^ny).
$$
Because of this, if $(Tx,x)$ is real for all $x$, then
\begin{align}
       \overline{(Tx,y)} & = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}(-i)^n (T(x+i^n y),x+i^ny) \\
    & = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}(-i)^n(T((-i)^nx+y),(-i)^nx+y) \\
    & =(Ty,x),
\end{align}
which gives the following for all $x,y$:
$$
 (Tx,y) = \overline{(Ty,x)}=(x,Ty).
$$
The polarization identity is used for a lot of such problems, and is worth learning, especially in the compact summation form shown above, which I picked up from Arveson's book on Spectral Theory.

Comment: Thanks. You seem to have the answer to all my questions today. This one I follow, the earlier one I'll need to work on.

Comment: @TomCollinge : I guess there's an overlap in our interests.